# Is there any self diagnosis method or device to know if there is an implant in my ear or auditory system?

Tags: x-rays, self-help

Is there any self diagnosis method or device to know if there is an implant in my ear or auditory system?

Will an x-ray show it? What kind of x-ray do I need to get?

Comment: One common cause of tinnitus is dehydration. Another one is consumption of too much sugar.

Comment: I haven't talked about tinnitus at all. What made you make this comment? Are you qualified to give this opinion?

Comment: Some people may believe wrongly that they have a strange implant in their heads when it is just tinnitus they have. Thought maybe you were one of them.

Comment: @Constantthin Even if I was, I can only know through diagnosis. If there is an implant or not. Why did you think it was dehydration and sugar and not any other cause? I have my own reasons to believe if there is an implant and it has nothing to do with what you suspected. If you can't contribute to any self-diagnosis methods, you shouldn't force some other reason onto others.

Comment: If one is uncertain the method of elimination is a good start. If so, the easiest way is to eliminate the minor things in one's daily routine first. But, you are saying that you are certain, so maybe this is not for you.